# Can I determine by code IMEI, whether the device is the Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: imei

Can I determine by code IMEI, whether the device is the Samsung Galaxy S3? If so, how? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do check your IMEI on this site: https://imeidata.net

And with samsung, try this link: https://imeidata.net/warranty/samsung

```
IMEI: 3564200525xxxx
Serial Number: RV1D53Jxxx
Model: SGH-M919
Unit Model: SGH-M919ZKATMB
Division: Mobile Phone (HHP)
Manufacturer: Tianjin Samsung Telecom Technology
Sold To: U.S.A
Production Date: May 16, 2013
Ship Date: May 16, 2013
Phone Age: 1 Year(s), 7 Month(s), 28 Day(s)
Factory Warranty Coverage: August 16, 2014
```

Comment: is this answer still relevant? The page doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

There probably is a pattern to IMEI numbers, i.e. first few digits are country of origin, second three are company, etc. but I am not aware if such information is public.

However, what you can do, is try with online services like http://imei-number.com/imei-number-lookup/ which provide such a service.

Also, most "unlock" services have imei check feature, to tell you the type of the phone and to what network is it locked.